# What does it mean if $\text{Ric} =0$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with vanishing Ricci curvature. Does this mean that every component of the Ricci curvature tensor vanshes, i.e., $R_{ij}=0$?

Comment: Yes indeed as we know that $Ric=R_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$ [Using Einstein summation convention]. Further $dx^i\otimes dx^j$ is a basis element so $Ric=0 \iff R_{ij}=0$.

Comment: May I know what is your definition of "vanishing Ricci curvature"?